# On Textbox change event how to show loading animation on Gridview data processing?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Asp.Net webpage where I have a textbox with calendar extender, when the user enters the date the loading animation should load while the grid data is processing.I have the below code (Jquery, HTML) which works only when the user enters the date using extender but not when the user keys in. None of my solutions working after applying Ajax UpdateProgress aswell. ANY suggestions would help.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("[id$='ddlCountry'], [id$='DateTxtBox']").change(function () {
            $('.blockMe').block({
                message: 'Loading...',
                css: { padding: '10px' }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<table  style="width:100%">
<tr>                           
<td>
<div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 60px; padding-bottom: 5px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden" class="table-responsive">
<table style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top:20px; width:100%;"> 
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:5%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">                           
    <asp:Label ID="DateFromlbl" class="text-muted" Style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; font-weight: 600" Text="Date From (MM/dd/yyyy):" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="DateTxtBox" Style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 600" Width="80px"  Height="20px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="DateTxtBox_OnTextChanged" runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="CalendarImg" runat="server" Width="18px" Height="18px" ImageUrl="~/DailyDownloads/Images/Calendar.PNG" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="DateFromCalenderExt" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateTxtBox" PopupButtonID="CalendarImg"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ForeColor="Red" id="reqName" controltovalidate="DateTxtBox" errormessage="Date Required"/>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])\/([0-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)\d\d$" ID="dateValidator"
     ControlToValidate="DateTxtBox" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Format. Use MM/DD/YYYY" runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td>
</tr>                                
<tr><td>
<table style="width:100%;">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>                        
<asp:Panel ID ="p1" runat="server">                         
    <td>                                     
    <asp:Label ID="Countrylbl" Style="font-size: 13px; text-align: right; font-weight: 600" class="text-muted" Text="Agencies:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" Style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" Width="50%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMunicipality_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </td> 
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DateTxtBox" EventName="TextChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

<div class="blockMe">

  <asp:GridView EnableEventValidation="false" ID="EmpGrd" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
       AllowSorting="true"  PageSize="25" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="EmpGrd_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="EmpGrd_Sorting" FooterStyle-BackColor="Black" CssClass="table table-condensed table-hover">
   <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
   <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpID" HeaderText="EmpID" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MtgRef" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="Name" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Employment" HeaderText="Employment" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="TaxAgency" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="JoinedDate" HeaderText="JoinedDate" ItemStyle-Width="14%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="CurrentAdvancedDate" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="DateofBirth" HeaderText="DateofBirth" ItemStyle-Width="14%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" SortExpression="NewAdvancedDate" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="JobDescription" HeaderText="JobDescription" ItemStyle-Width="30%" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" Visible="true" SortExpression="LegalDescription" />
   </Columns>
   <EmptyDataTemplate><label class="label label-danger"  style="font-size:13px; font-weight:600;">No records found !</label></EmptyDataTemplate>
   <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="GridPager" />
   </asp:GridView> 
   
</div>
    
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlcountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DateTxtBox" EventName ="TextChanged"/>
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: You have a `.change(function...`, you could try adding (or changing that to) `.keyup()`. No guarantees. Try a few things and update your question with what you have tried and the results.

Comment: No luck I tried `.keyup()`, not working.

Comment: I am still struck here, any suggestions?